# How to choose random from one column and an adjacent column

Tags: google-sheets

For example I have this list of a product and a price:

| Product | Price |
| --- | --- |
| potato masher | € 27 |
| dish brush | € 20 |
| rolling pin | € 17 |
| doormat | € 20 |
| mop | € 22 |

To choose a random product, I use `=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A$1:$A$5)),1)`

Is there a formula or way to randomly choose from two adjacent columns and put it in two other columns? So when it randomly chooses the potato masher, it chooses € 27 for the adjacent row and not for example another random price from that column (Which happens when I use the =INDEX with B instead of A).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have Microsoft365:

[image]

- Select two cells, e.g: `D1:E1`.
- Use formula `=INDEX(A2:B6,RANDBETWEEN(1,5),0)`.
- Confirm through: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you do have MS365, you don't need to CSE-confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made a mistake, it's not in Excel, but in google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(A1:B6, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A1:A6)))
```